# Android ArrayAdapter within setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I hope you can help me with this newbie q:)
I'm using Android Studio.
I'm trying to use an ArrayAdapter within setOnItemClickListener but got an error and I dont know what I'm doing wrong here. Please help me:)

This "listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simplerow, arrayView);" gives this Error:

cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, int, java.util.Arraylist)'

-----MyCode------

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                            long arg3)
    {
        String name = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        //Log.d("name", "name: "+name);
        int j = 0;
        while (j < livsmedelsNameValues.size()) {
            if (livsmedelsNameValues.get(j).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Foodlist: "+name)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 62; i++) {
                    test[0] = livsmedelsNameValues.get(i+j);
                    //Log.d("test", "test: " + test[0]);
                    arrayView.add(test[0].toString());
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, arrayView);


        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    }

});
```

Comment: Please post error log...

Comment: arrayView should be array string. check if your passing correct string array

Comment: final ArrayList<String> arrayView = new ArrayList<String>();
This is what it looks like....anyway after one of the answer I got the code error solved but now the problem is that the listVIew is not set with this info from "arrayView".
Thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
R.layout.simplerow, arrayView);

here 1st parameter for ArrayAdapter must be context. so
in you onclick listener "this" means OnItemClickListener not Context. use "this" if code inside Activity class.

now use getBaseContext() or getApplicationContext() or your activity.this or  getActivity() instead of "this" so use

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(),
```

R.layout.simplerow, arrayView);

or

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.simplerow, arrayView);
```

Comment: Thanks for that no errors:)
Any ideas why the listview is not updated with this new stuff?
 mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );

Could it be something with that I already have used this listview and trying to input new info?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, arrayView);
```

`this` is not a valid context. Use `ActivityName.this` or `getActivity()` if in fragment